# jQuery disable button if all span element don't contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do some kind of validation. So I have inputs to type some text. Values from inputs are passed to spans. Now I want to disable button if this span are empty. So basically if I don't type anything in inputs spans are empty and button is disabled. When both spans are not empty then button is enabled. Below is my code. I figure it out that my second on change function don't work. Anyone could help me?

```js
$('#input').on('change keyup', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#summary_a').html(value);
});

$('#input-b').on('change keyup', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#summary_b').html(value);
});

$('.btn-final').prop("disabled", true);
$('.summary').on('change', function(){
      alert("test");
        $(this).each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
                $('.btn-final').prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $('.btn-final').prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">

<input type="text" id="input-b">

<p>a: <br> <span id="summary_a" class="summary"></span></p>

<p>b: <br> <span id="summary_b" class="summary"></span></p>

<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit-form-1" class="btn btn-yellow btn-final">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You need to apply a much cleaner approach like below:-***

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('#input').on('change keyup', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#summary_a').html(value);
  checkempty(); // call a function
});

$('#input-b').on('change keyup', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#summary_b').html(value);
  checkempty(); // call a function
});

$('.btn-final').prop("disabled", true);
function checkempty() {
  var $nonempty = $('.summary').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == ''
  }); // check for empty spans
  if ($nonempty.length > 0) { // if empty spans available
    $('.btn-final').prop("disabled", true); // disable button
  } else {
    $('.btn-final').prop("disabled", false); // otherwise enable it
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">

<input type="text" id="input-b">

<p>a: <br> <span id="summary_a" class="summary"></span></p>

<p>b: <br> <span id="summary_b" class="summary"></span></p>

<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit-form-1" class="btn btn-yellow btn-final">
```

***Working jSFiddle:-*** https://jsfiddle.net/9a69nttj/

Comment: @AlivetoDie you the boss! Works flawless! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MMPL1  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have one more small question. Can I add class to all my inputs for example trigger and do something like this? 
$('.trigger').on('change', function(){
checkempty();
})

Comment: @MMPL1  you have to ask a new question for that. Because i din't get you properly, and asking again and agin in comments is not a good idea. Address me the link and if i will free i will answer that. Otherwise some-one for-sure answer you